# Saving the state of a random number generator in haskell

Tags: haskell, random

I'm currently using the `Crypto.Random` and `Crypto.Random.DRBG` Haskell libraries for generating random numbers. However, I find myself needing to store their states in some form of file (e.g. a `.txt` file), since I want to continue using the same generator in some later point in time (this because I need two separate programs to generate the same random numbers in the same order).
The above mentioned libraries are not instances of the `Show` function. Does anyone know how I could store the state of the mentioned generator?

Comment: Why are you using crypto-strength PRNG, if you want to persist and replay state? Just use StdGen.

Comment: Because I'm programming a cryptographic protocol and need the properties of DRBG. And it's not that I need to replay state. As I said, I need two (different) programs to generate the same numbers (at different points in time), without needing to transfer them.

Comment: Looking at the [sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/DRBG/0.5/doc/html/src/Crypto-Random-DRBG-HMAC.html#State) it seems that it would be easy to add persistence (such as by implementing `Serialize`) to `State`. One problem I see there is the hash algorithm, which is represented as a function and so it can't be serialized. But this information could be supplied by a user during deserialization.

Comment: Yeah, I thought something like that, but I need it to be automatized.
At the moment I'm just generating a random number of the proper length and using it as a seed for the future state of the PRNG. It's not really a proper state saving, but it ensures that the other PRNG generates de same numbers.

Comment: You can always submit a github issue to request instances for Show, Read or perhaps Serialize for some of the DRBG generators.  The maintainer is lazy and a bit slow, but this shouldn't be hard.  Alternatively, you could submit a patch.

Comment: @PetrPudlák The hash DRBG (or HMAC DRBG) is very slow.  Unless you have a particular need, the CTR DRBG is the DRBG of choice.  It is fortunate that adding these instances to CTR should also prove easy.  [See the benchmarks](http://tommd.github.io/posts/RNG-Bench.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform serialization of CtrDRBG using the git version of DRBG (since commit 9da47c4dabf9f6976edcbf938c4a1a4b95e09b0c).  EDIT: this is now on hackage.  To Install:

```
cabal update
cabal install DRBG
```

And now you should be able to use `Data.Serialize`'s `encode` and `decode` functions on `CtrDRBG`.

EDIT: I feel like I should mention that, like all NIST SP 800-90 generators, DRBG might not give the properties you might expect.  It is true that the generator is deterministic, but your requests perturb the state so generating N bytes twice does not result in the same bytes as a single request to generate 2*N bytes.  This is due to the backtracking resistance of the generators.  A buffering strategy that always makes consistent-sized requests and performs concatenation under the covers could hide this behavior.